# Apache Solr atomic update results in NullPointerException

Tags: solr

Im trying to partially update a document via an atomic update, when I do so, the web sever responds with a 500 status with the stacktrace of

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.getFieldFromHierarchy(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:301)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.mergeChildDoc(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:398)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.getUpdatedDocument(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:697)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:372)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:50)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:223)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:475)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:75)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:507)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:145)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:121)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:84)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2566)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:756)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:397)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a new clean instance of apache solr
2. Create a new core
3. Add a new document with the following data (in development mode Solr should create fields automatically) using Solr Admin's document upload tool.

   `{ "id": "1", "network_s": "original value" }`
   [image: example of adding a new document]
4. Then proceed to upload a new JSON command to update the previously uploaded document.

`[{"id": "1", "network_s": {"set":"Something else"}}]`

[image: example of updating a document]

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong but I'm following the documentation exactly. Im using Solr version `8.1.1` and reading the *latest* documentation of 7.7.

Comment: Any `NullPointerException` should not really be propagated to the end user, so I'd at least [create a bug report at the official JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SOLR?).

Comment: Is this true only for production instances though?

Comment: Well, they shouldn't occur at all - the specific case that triggers the nullpointer should be tested earlier and a proper exception or error should be generated.

Comment: I just downgraded to 7.7 (I'm new to Solr), and it appears to work. I think the 8.1 release either broke the functionality or changed the way you operate atomic updating. That being said, the documentation for 8.x isn't released yet so I cant tell which is which until someone looks at the JIRA ticket or the documentation is released.

Comment: It shouldn't change in a manner that gives you an NPE, so this is certainly a bug.

Comment: Well thanks for the help, just in case you're interested: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug within the Solr 8.1 release. Downgrading to 7.7 fixes the issue until its patched. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13523